# How to set express session cookie to expire on the response

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies

Using `express js` and `express-session`, I want to set the cookie to expire on the `response` of the current `request`.

I tried to do something like:
`req.session.cookie.maxAge = 0` or `req.session.cookie.expires = new Date()`

But I'm getting the following error:

> ReplyError: ERR invalid expire time in set

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `new Date()` gets called when the node app starts, so every moment from then redis is looking at a negative TTL, and blows up.

If you want to expire the cookie, use `session.destroy();`